# Omis­si­bil­ity of the deﬁ­n­ite ar­ti­cle “the” be­fore at­tribu­tive mod­i­ﬁers of per­sonal names in Amer­i­can English

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles, names, zero-article, omissibility

Are **both** in­clu­sion and omis­sion of the deﬁ­n­ite ar­ti­cle
*the* be­fore per­sonal names that have at­tribu­tive
mod­i­fiers (nom­i­nal or ad­jec­ti­val or both) con­sid­ered gram­mat­i­cal in Amer­i­can English?

For ex­am­ple:

1. This was described by novelist John Steinbeck.
   This was described by **the** novelist John Steinbeck.
2. This was mentioned by notable scholar John Smith.
   This was mentioned by **the** notable scholar John Smith.
3. None other than mercurial President Trump.
   None other than **the** mercurial President Trump.
4. A feature of colonial-age Europe.
   A feature of **the** colonial-age Europe.
5. We returned to snowy Canada.
   We returned to **the** snowy Canada.
6. Famous author John Smith believes....
   **The** famous author John Smith believes....

If so, do they mean dif­fer­ent things or the same thing, and is
one ever prefer­able over the other?

(I live in Amer­ica, and so my ques­tion is in ref­er­ence to
Amer­i­can English only.)

Comment: It's better to use the article in this situation. Otherwise you sound too much like [Dan Brown](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000844.html)

Comment: I think 4 and 5 should not have "the".  I do not talk about "the ... Canada" nor "the ... Europe".  I do talk about the author, the president, the scholar, the novelist.

Comment: @GEdgar: That's not entirely accurate. You do talk about about "the Canada of yore," and "the Europe we all know and adore, as opposed to ...", as well as "a very different Australia."

Comment: Interesting question. _We returned to the Canada we remembered_, but not *_We returned to Canada we remembered_. And _I described the John Steinbeck I remembered_, but not *_I described John Steinbeck I remembered_.

Comment: @TinfoilHat & Ricky Yes, those "concrete with elaboration" examples are clear, and require a definite article because they're definite. The question is about a declarative case which isn't yet definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nouns**

In the case of nouns, both versions are acceptable: with the definite article, the proper name functions as an appositive dependent, and it is the first noun that is the head of the noun phrase (NP). In contrast, without the article, it is the proper name that is the head, while the first noun is an omissible **embellishment** ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), p. 520). As for the possible difference in meaning, I doubt there is anything systematic one could say, and in any case, whatever it is, it would normally be slight.

**Adjectives**

In the case of adjectives, the acceptability of putting or withholding the definite article depends on the adjective, and sometimes even on the context. For example, it may well be absolutely unacceptable to omit the definite article in front of *incomparable*, as in

> ***the incomparable Mary Pickford.***

On the other hand, an adjective like *young* can appear both with and without the definite article. So we can have

> ***The young John Burton Davis Jr.** devoured these Sunday funnies.*

and we can also have

> *Life as businessman for **young John Hope Bryant** began with a modest but life-changing $40 investment*.

(Not to mention that it can appear with the indefinite article as well: *starring **a young John Travolta***).

An adjective like *beautiful* usually appears with the *the*, but not always: e.g. the following is attested:

> *And **beautiful Helen** with a cousin, a little boy who couldn't be older than eight.*

On the other hand, in some constructions *the* is probably obligatory. One example is when *the*+name appears as an appositive supplement to *wife*, as in

> Henry married his fifth wife, **the beautiful Catherine Howard.**
>
> <sup>From Gifford, Clive. *10 Kings and Queens Who Changed the World.* United States: Kingfisher, 2009. [(link)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=LtkEYNC8NuPx5gLP4oSQDQ&q=%22wife%2C+the+beautiful%22&oq=%22wife%2C+the+beautiful%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...102176.102780.0.103314.4.4.0.0.0.0.104.341.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.6Rll55u5Pew)</sup>

(All examples but the last one are from the *Corpus of Contemporary American English,* [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/).)

CGEL says the following (p. 520):

> Adjectives occur as embellishments of proper names in two constructions: in bare NPs or in ones determined (redundantly) by *the*, as in the last two examples of [5ii] [*the **inimitable** Oscar Wilde, the **distraught** Empress Alexandra*]. The bare NP construction is restricted to a fairly small set of adjectives with emotive colouring: *beautiful* and *ugly*, *young* and *old*, and so on. The determined NP construction allows a somewhat larger range including *beautiful, dazzling, incomparable, inimitable, irrepressible, unfortunate, wretched,* and adjectives denoting emotional states such as *distraught, furious, jealous.* Such adjectives can in general modify the head of weak proper names: *the ill-fated Titanic.*

(A **weak** proper name is one that includes the definite article, like *the Thames* or *the Bronx*. (CGEL, p. 517))

**Adjective + geographic name**

Here, too, both bare and determined forms are attested in COCA<sup>1</sup> and elsewhere:

<sup><sup>1</sup>which is where the examples come unless specified otherwise.</sup>

Determined:

> *A letter to the editor in November 1940 describes a similar scene in Louisville, Kentucky: “This morning while sitting in our office in the Starks Building reading about **the war-torn Europe,** the men in one of the insurance offices sang 'God Bless America'.*
> <sup>From Kaskowitz, Sheryl. *God Bless America: The Surprising History of an Iconic Song.* United Kingdom: OUP USA, 2013. [(link)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/God_Bless_America/qRRpAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22office%20in%20the%20Starks%20Building%20reading%20about%20the%20war-torn%20Europe%22&pg=PT65&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22office%20in%20the%20Starks%20Building%20reading%20about%20the%20war-torn%20Europe%22)</sup>
>
> *I had arrived in Europe years before mass tourism and study programs abroad abounded. It was perhaps the last of **the old Europe,** still in its post-World War II burst of liberation and creativity.*
>
> *In the end, Powell's efforts for consensus were undermined by the defection of France and Germany. Defense Secretary Donald Rumsfeld spoke slightingly of **the old Europe,** as though placing more reliance on some new Europe of formerly Communist-ruled East European states.*

Bare:

> *Peter H. Amann taught European history as few could, filtered through the perspective of a Jew who helped his family escape **war-torn Europe** ahead of the Nazis as his relatives were put to their deaths.*
>
> *They wore tiny army uniforms of green or sand brown, not the elegance of **old Europe** but the utility of the World Wars.*
>
> *Greece may be falling apart, but from its quintessential red grape, St. George, comes a heady copper-edged ros redolent with iris, beetroot, robust cherry and roasted tangerine. I could have drunk it all year. Beyond that lies a story in how **old Europe** can regain currency, and not just in an EU rescue sort of way.*

Comment: Thank you this clarifies most of it, but I feel that geographic names are a special case in which `the` can **never** occur with adjective modifiers, unlike personal names where it's almost always allowed at least optionally if not required outright, like you said. In my examples #4 and 5 it doesn't feel right to say `"Pictures of the war-torn Europe,"` `"a feature of the colonial Africa,"` or `"We returned to the snowy Canada."`

Comment: Although, in reference to the above comment, these constructions would be permissible if I had previously alluded to these geographic names, i.e. in the true definitive-article context. If I recently talked about Canada I could then say something about `the snowy Canada`, or if I recently talked about Europe I could probably say `the ... [modifier] Europe.` But otherwise, in a general not-previously-alluded-to context, `the` is not permissible with these geographic names -- unlike personal names.

Comment: @geneb. In the various corpora, I don't see any evidence for there being such a prohibition in the case of geographical names. The bare form does seem to be more frequent, but the determined form is by no means rare. I've added a new section in my answer that addresses this.